# Adding a new column to data (from excel file)

Tags: r, statistics

I am working in RStudio. I have a data from an Excel file named "X12_5_3":

```
    P,     1,    2,    3
 5350,    17,   44,   50
25831,   788,  890, 1409
 5594,   968,  218,  344
10359,   212,  185,  306
```

I want to create a new column called `weight` and add values `0.4` for the first two rows, and `0.6` for the last two rows.

My code for this moment is:

```
data<- X12_5_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposed solution:

1. Setup base dataframe as referenced:

   X12_5_3 <- data.frame( "P" = c(5350, 25831, 5594, 10359),
                          "1" = c(17,788,968,212),
                          "2" = c(44,890,218,185),
                          "3" = c(50, 1409, 344, 306) )
2. Creating a data frame from a vector of 4 values

   weight <- data.frame(c( 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
3. Bind both dataframes together with `cbind()` after the last column of data

   X12_5_3 <- cbind(X12_5_3, weight)
4. Rename the columns with `colnames`

   colnames(X12_5_3) <- c("P", "1", "2", "3", "weight")
5. View the updated dataframe:

   X12_5_3

This will show your dataframe, named `X12_5_3` with the added column data.

### Console Output:

```
> X12_5_3 <- data.frame( "P" = c(5350, 25831, 5594, 10359),
+                        "1" = c(17,788,968,212),
+                        "2" = c(44,890,218,185),
+                        "3" = c(50, 1409, 344, 306) )
> 
> weight <- data.frame( c( 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
> 
> X12_5_3 <- cbind(X12_5_3, weight)  
> colnames(X12_5_3) <- c("P", "1", "2", "3", "weight")    
> 
> X12_5_3
      P   1   2    3 weight
1  5350  17  44   50    0.4
2 25831 788 890 1409    0.4
3  5594 968 218  344    0.6
4 10359 212 185  306    0.6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#your code 
data <- X12_5_3

#add the weight column
data$weight <- c(.4,.4,.6,.6)

#rename the columns (optional)
colnames(data) <- c("P", "1", "2", "3", "weight") 

#done, ... and to view the result
print(data)
```